# Parentheses in error message cause expect_error test to fail

Tags: r, testthat

Why doesn't this test pass?

```
my_fun <- function(x){
  if(x > 1){stop("my_fun() must be called on values of x less than or equal to 1")}
  x
}

library(testthat)
expect_error(my_fun(2),
             "my_fun() must be called on values of x less than or equal to 1")
```

It returns the error message:

> Error: error$message does not match "my_fun() must be called on values
>   of x less than or equal to 1". Actual value: "my_fun() must be called
>   on values of x less than or equal to 1"

If you remove the `()` from both the function and the test, the test *does* pass, leading me to think it's something about the parentheses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `expect_error`, you are passing a regular expression, not just a string. Parentheses are special characters in regular expressions and must be escaped. (Parentheses are used for grouping in regular expressions). To handle the parens, just change `expect_error` to the below:

```
expect_error(my_fun(2),
             "my_fun\\(\\) must be called on values of x less than or equal to 1")
```

Or more generally, specify `fixed = TRUE` to test the string as an exact match:

```
expect_error(my_fun(2),
             "my_fun() must be called on values of x less than or equal to 1",
             fixed = TRUE)
```